# How to set up differents controllers with the same route in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

This is my web routes:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'proveedor_auth'
], function ($router) {
    require base_path('routes/custom/proveedor_routes.php');
});

Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'tendero_auth'
], function ($router) {
    require base_path('routes/custom/tendero_routes.php');
});
```

I tried with Route::Group but just only works with "tendero_auth".

There is other better way?

proveedor_auth:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if (Auth::guard('web_proveedor')->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('log');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

tendero_auth:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if (Auth::guard('web_tendero')->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('log');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Or is there some library to do this for me?

Comment: could you paste both routes includes?

Comment: Umm, Off course

Answer (score 0):

tendero_routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('tendero.index');
});
```

proveedor_routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('proveedores.index');
});
```

My idea is change later the annonymous function by a ResourceController. This is only for testing.

Answer (score 0):

So obviously the second one overwrites the first.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('tendero.index');
    });
});
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
     Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('proveedores.index');
     });
});
```

when doing the `php artisan route:list` there will be only the second listed:

```
php artisan route:list
+--------+----------+-----+------+---------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI | Name | Action  | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-----+------+---------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /   |      | Closure | auth       |
+--------+----------+-----+------+---------+------------+
```

It seems to be also confirmed here:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/multiple-routes-with-same-url-but-different-names

> I believe that URLs are indexed and keyed on their URL - so therefore
>   the first one would be overridden completely by the first one.